# java/spring- getting NoClassDefFoundError at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, rmi

I am trying to initialise an RMI client for which I have used Spring.

Now, the application's RMI context is stored in file= rmiClientAppContext.xml

The relevant code for using the above file is given below--

```
 //RMI Client Application Context is started...
     ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("rmiClientAppContext.xml");
```

However, when I try and run the program, this is the error I am getting--

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractApplicationContext.java:164)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:90)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.java:59)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:61)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:136)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
```

On further investigation of the first line of error message above, I found that

```
"164 is not a valid line number in org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext"
```

What have i done wrong here? I am using Spring v3.1.3
How do I resolve the above error? Also, exactly which JARs do I have to include for the RMI client? And is there any specific order in which those JARs should be added to Java build path in Eclipse?

Comment: Can you please include your main class in the post? what seems to make the problem is the missing jar file associated with apache commons logging . are you trying to instantiate a logger in your main class? did you add the corresponding bean in your context.xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case you should include commons-logging-1.1.1.jar in your client classpath. Spring-Core depends on it.

In general I suggest you to use [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) or similar tool to manage your dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are missing very important spring-web jar file. Add this to your pom file to fix this issue.

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```